# jQuery How to get current selected drop down element when blur on another input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click on input #phone and get the current dial-code from the selected country, and put it in the input #dialCode.

html:

```
<input id="phone" type="text">
<input id="dialCode" type="text">
```

jQuery:

```
// this works fine
$('.iti__country-list li').click(function(){
        $("#dialCode").val($(this).data('dial-code'));
})

// but I want, on #phone blur get the above data and put it in dial-code
$('#phone').blur(function(){ ...
```

UPDATE:

This is the original code:

https://cdpn.io/jonmnoj/fullpage/PoqMrRL?#

The problem is that when I submit, it doesn't pass the Dial-code: +1, +44, etc.

Also, the phone input, can also change the Dial-code. Ex. I can type +1 or +44, so the drop down " .iti__country-list " is not the only way to select the country code.

I tried a few things based on K-Galalem's suggestions, but no success either:

```
$('.iti__country-list li').on({
  change: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "YELLOW");
    $('.iti__country-list li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  },
  blur: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "BLUE");
    $('.iti__country-list li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  },
  click: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "GREEN");
  }
}); 

$("#phone").on({
  focus: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F09");
    $('.iti__country-list li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  },
  change: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F09");
    $('.iti__country-list li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  },
  blur: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "LIME");
    $("#dialCode").val($('.iti__country-list li.selected').data('dial-code'));
  },
  click: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "CYAN");
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you not just get the value from `$("#dialCode").val()`?

Comment: @freedomn-m That input is just to keep it hidden until the user submits the form with the dialCode

Comment: Maybe, but the value will still be the same, will it not?  (at the time of blur, dialCode and selected li data-dial-code will be the same)

Comment: re:edit - the idea is to *keep* the "selected" class against the li - so remove the li.blur removes the class.  Only remove the li.selected if you're changing the dial-code manually - though can't see in your code where you extract the dial-code from the phone number.   TBH I'm still confused why you need to know the li - just use #dialCode value.   the LI sets dialCode, the input sets dialCode.  Why would you read the li dialcode if the input has set it?   There seems no need to read the li dialcode.

Comment: Your cdpn.io link doesn't show source - just how it's currently working.  Can you copy to jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @freedomn-m suggestions to get the li.selected and to pick the selected directly, I found out that there was actually a selected item in the drop down of the flags, so I selected it directly. I don't know how to give credit though. But here is the code that worked out:

```
$('#phone').on({
      change: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "f09");
        $("#dialCode").val($('.iti__selected-flag').attr("title"));
      },
      blur: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
        $("#dialCode").val($('.iti__selected-flag').attr("title"));
      },
      click: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "LIME");
        $("#dialCode").val($('.iti__selected-flag').attr("title"));
      }
    });
    $("#dialCode").val($('.iti__selected-flag').attr("title"));
```

Comment: Just glad you got it work, you can accept your own answer if it could have been answered from the question detailed provided (which it can - I put it like that as we get questions like "my code doesn't work, here's the code" - answer: "my PC was off" (or some other trivial, *unrelated* answer that no-one could have guessed from the question))

Answer (score 0):

you can add a CSS class to distinguish the selected item like this:

```js
$('.iti__country-list li').click(function(){
        $('.iti__country-list li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
})

$('#phone').blur(function(){ 
        $("#dialCode").val($('.iti__country-list li.selected').data('dial-code'));
```

Comment: Thanks @K-Galalem, great idea. But for some reason, is not working. Keeps doing the same as before. I forgot to specify something (see update).